# Why does my aws-cli build work on the intermediate container during buildtime, but not on the final container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, alpine-linux

I've been trying to put aws-cli on an Alpine based docker image I have. I found someone's tips for including the appropriate libraries for glibc [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4685#issuecomment-615872019) and I was able to make things run smoothly on my docker build.  If I call the aws executable in the build process from the intermediate container it's being built on, it works.

After COPYing the aws binary directory to the destination, the files all are transferred, but the aws executable no longer works.  I try to do it from either the CMD or docker exec and I just get an error that the file doesn't exist:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

This is the docker repo I started with:  https://hub.docker.com/r/alfg/nginx-rtmp/.  I'm just pasting the aws cli build code below after the ffmpeg FROM  block,  and adding the `COPY --from=2` line further down in this question.

Here is the build section for the aws cli:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

ENV GLIBC_VER=2.31-r0

# install glibc compatibility for alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/examples \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && rm glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

And here are the final steps of my Dockerfile which copy the files and update PATH:

```
COPY --from=0 /usr/local/nginx /usr/local/nginx
COPY --from=0 /etc/nginx /etc/nginx
COPY --from=1 /usr/local /usr/local
COPY --from=1 /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2 /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2
COPY --from=2 /usr/local/aws-cli /usr/local/aws-cli

# Add NGINX path, AWS-CLI path, config and static files.
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/usr/local/nginx/sbin:/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin"
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template
RUN mkdir -p /opt/data && mkdir /www
ADD static /www/static

EXPOSE 1935
EXPOSE 80

CMD envsubst "$(env | sed -e 's/=.*//' -e 's/^/\$/g')" < \
  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
  nginx
```

The docker build runs succesfully and I can launch containers from the image. I've also put things like `aws s3 ls s3://my-public-bucket` in the Dockerfile at the end of the aws-cli block, and during the build they run succesfully and can pull from s3.

The only thing I can see wrong in the build is in the image below - it happens during the glibc/aws build, but the build still succesfully completes and the binary is functional afterwards:

```
/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is not a symbolic link
```

[image: /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is not a symbolic link]

Comment: I would encourage to do a couple of things. first, make sure that you show the error that you're getting and second to be a little more explicit on what's failing and when. What you gave doesn't give a lot of context into what your problem is.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - I got interrupted and just hit submit when I hadn't finished getting all the info together. I've updated the question now.

Comment: Why not just install Python and then `pip install awscli`? Also, are you sure you copied all the glibc libraries to the final image? Looks like you just copied `aws-cli` without the libraries. Are you sure it's statistically compiled? Last but not least, run `ldd` on the binary to see which libraries are missing.

Comment: @kichik I specifically wanted aws-cli v2 support, which isn't build on pip yet.   It would appear you're right that I failed to copy over the libraries. ldd shows a couple missing.